# Sublime 3 module search directory to match webpack

Tags: webpack, sublimetext3

Is there any way for sublime to find modules based on webpack's search paths?

i.e. Given folder structure like this

```
/src
|-- /modules
|-- /models
```

and `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports.resolve = {
  root: [
    path.resolve('./'),
    path.resolve('./src/')
  ],
  extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src']
}
```

Is there a setting in sublime 3 where sublime won't falsely highlight the following for missing module?

```
import xyz from 'models/xyc';
import abc from 'modules/abc';
```